# Pass by value vs Pass by reference with polymorphism

Tags: c#, polymorphism, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

The following code shows a pass by reference example using `ref` keyword.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int c1 = 10;
        ClassC c2 = new ClassC(10);
        ClassA a = new ClassB();

        a.MethodA(ref c1); Console.WriteLine(c1);
        a.MethodB(ref c2); Console.WriteLine(c2.getC());

        Console.Read();
    }
}

class ClassA //base class
{
    public virtual void MethodA(ref int c1)
    {
        c1 = c1 + 5;
    }
    public virtual void MethodB(ref ClassC c2)
    {
        c2.setC(c2.getC() + 5);
    }
}

class ClassB : ClassA  //ssubclass
{
    public override void MethodA(ref int c1)
    {
        c1 = c1 - 5;
    }
    public void MethodB(ref ClassC c2)
    {
        c2.setC(c2.getC() - 5);
    }
}


class ClassC //just a class with a variable c with get/set methods
{
    protected int c;
    public ClassC(int CValue) { c = CValue; }
    public void setC(int cnew) { this.c = cnew; }
    public int getC() { return c; }
}
```

If there is no `ref` keyword, it would be pass by value and the output I get would be 10 and 15.

However, with the `ref` keyword, I actually get an output of 5 and 15! Why does the code without ref point to the method in `classA` while the code with ref points to the method in `classB`? I'm guessing it has got to do something with polymorphism - `classB` inherits `class A`, but how do you explain it?

Comment: Read your compiler warnings; they are telling you what is going on here.

Answer (score 2):

> Why does the code without ref point to the method in
>   classA while the code with ref point to the method in classB?

Your code calls `ClassB.MethodA` and `ClassA.MethodB`. Always. There is no deal with `ref`...

Answer (score 2):

ClassB.MethodB does not overrides ClassA.MethodB, and you are calling MethodB from a ClassA reference.

if you want ClassB.MethodB to get called in that case, you'll have to add the override keyword, if not .net identify it as another method.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a question of `ref` or not.

You have `ClassA a = new ClassB();`, that is `a` has compile-time type `ClassA`, but the run-time type is more derived, namely `ClassB`.

1: You call the `virtual` method `MethodA`. This method ***is*** overridden by the `ClassB`, so because of the virtual dispatch, the overridden implementation is used.

2: You call the `virtual` method `MethodB`. This method is (inherited but) ***not*** overridden. Therefore its "original" (and only) implementation in `ClassA` is used. `ClassA` is the compile-time type of `a`, as I said. The fact that `ClassB` intoduces a ***new*** method with the same name and signature is not relevant. Maybe your omitted the `override` keyword by mistake? The compiler gave you a warning about hiding a method.

Always avoid introducing a new member (in a derived class) which hides an existing member inherited from the base class. Instead, try to use a new name (identifyer), or a new signature, which does not conflict with the existing member. Or maybe don't derive from the base class at all.